# Visualforce Page in Salesforce1 - error in visualization

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

I have a problem. I made a visualforce page in order to visualize a related list customized. I have the following code:

```
<apex:page standardController="**" extensions="***" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        function redirec(redirectUrl){
            sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, redirectUrl, true, '', openSuccess);
        }
    </script>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!**}" > 
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!***}" var="ret">
                <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">                      
                         <apex:outputPanel >{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.***.Label}</apex:outputPanel>
                      </apex:facet>
                    <apex:commandLink target="_top" action="{!URLFOR('/' + ret.***)}">{!ret.***}</apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.***.Label}" value="{!ret.***}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.***.Label}" value="{!ret.***}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.***.Label}" value="{!ret.***}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.***.Label}" value="{!ret.***}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.***.Fields.***.Label}" value="{!ret.***}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>             
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I visualice it in Salesforce classic (web) and it runs crrectly, but when I visualice in Salesforce1 it becomes with an strange css.

I need to visualize my visualforce page in Salesforce1 but I can't vizaulize it correctly. What do I need to do differently with my code?

Do I need to use any special labels?

[image]

Comment: quick fix is use `standardstylesheets="true"` to fix it completely you need to make it SF1 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks better:

[image]

But we want that the table appears similar to the fields abode.

Could you help us?

Thanks and best regards